# Discriminant ideal in a member of Barsotti-Tate Group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schemes, etale-cohomology, group-schemes

Let $S = \operatorname{Spec} R$ an affine scheme (in our case latter a complete dvr) and $p$ a prime. Then *Barsotti-Tate* group or $p$-divisible group $G$ of height $h$ over $S$
is an inductive system

$$(G_n, i_n:G_n \to G_{n+1})$$

where $G_n$ are finite, locally free
group schemes of order $p^{nh}$, such that all $i_n$ are closed embeddings with $G_n=G_{n+1}[p^n]$ (equality of sub-groupschemes).

I have a question about a proposition I found in my seminar notes (more precisely a strange reduction step there):

Assume, that for our BT group the base scheme $S= \operatorname{Spec} R$ is spectrum $R$ is a **complete, discrete valuation ring.** with alg. closed residue field $k=R/ \mathfrak{m}_R$. That's a meaningful reduction in light of the *fpqc-descent*. Denote it's fraction field by $F:=Frac(R)$.

Let $G_{n}$ an arbitrary member of the inductive system of the Barsotti-Tate group.  Denote by $G_{\nu, F}:= G_{n} \times_R \operatorname{Spec} F$ the generic fiber. The proposition tells:

> **Proposition**: The **discriminant ideal** $\mathcal{D}_{G_n/R} \subset \mathcal{O}_{G_n}$ of the $G_{n}$ depends only on $G_{n, F}$. (in the sense that all parameters determine the ideal sheaf can be extracted from $G_{n, F}$)

The proof begins with a statement I not understand:

It says that the claim above is trivial if $p \in R^{\times}$, ie $p$ invertible in $R$. So assume $p \in \mathfrak{m}_R$ [...]

That's exacly the **question**: Why is the statement of the Proposition in the case case $p \in R^{\times}$ trivial? Any idea why?

An alternative (or better "classical") proof can be found in J. Tate's paper $p$-Divisible Groups. But the concern of this question is only to understand the "triviality" above.

Comment: If $p \in R^\times$ then the discriminant ideal is trivial because all $G_n$ are etale.

Comment: @DavidHansen: but why $p \in R^\times$ imply that $G_n$ is etale?

Comment: In Tate's paper I mentioned above I found indeed that the discriminant ideal is generated by a power of $p$ (page 164, Prop. 2), but it's a non trivial result. SoI not see why the implication $p \in R^\times \Rightarrow G_n$ etale is "elementary". Could you sketch the proof or give a reference for the argument?

Comment: @MortyPB. The following is a standard fact (found in most introductory references on group schemes): Any finite flat group scheme of $p$-power order is \'etale if $p$ is invertible on the base. To prove this, reduce to checking this over a field, and then use that multiplication by $p^N$ is simultaneously $0$ for $N \gg 0$ (by assumption) and unramified (as the map on tangent spaces is given by $p^N$, which is invertible), so the group scheme is geometrically reduced (and thus \'etale).

Comment: Ok, so over a field the story follows from a decomposition into etale and connected part. Structure theorem tells about the connected part that it's of order coprime to $p$, so it's trivial by Lagrange. So over field it's fine.

Comment: The last part of your argument I not understand: Why the fact that multiplication by $p^N$ for $N$ big enough ($N$ bigger then the group order) acts as zero and induce simultaneously an unramified morphism, imply that $G$ is geometrically reduced?

Comment: Unramified finite type schemes over a field are \'etale and hence geometrically reduced.

Comment: yes, I see. Last remark: how do you perform the reduction of the problem from "over $R$" to "over a field"?

Comment: A finitely presented flat map is \'etale if it is fibrewise \'etale

Comment: @Anonymous: Sorry for digging out this thread but there is still a detail in your proof of the claim that Any finite flat group scheme over $k$ of $p$-power order is \'etale if $p$ is invertible on the base. We By Deligne theorem the multiplication by $p^N$ on $G$ indeed kills $G$; in other words the map $p^N: G \to G$ factorize over $Spec(k)$. Then you claim that the map on tangent spaces of $G$ induced by $p^N$ is also given by multiplication by $p^N$? Question: why the induced maps on tangent spaces are given by multiplications by $p^N$?

Comment: More precisely I understand that the induced map over tangent spaces over neutral element $e \in G$ is the multiplication by $p^N$-map. But over other points of $G$ I'm not sure why this is true. Could you give a reference for the proof you gave above. Meanwhile I found another proof of this claim but I would like to understand yours.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this until now. Looks like you got an answer elsewhere

Comment: @Anonymous: No problem, yes meanwhile I got an answer. But could you tell me:
was this exactly the idea you had in mind? namely we want to deduce
that the multiplication map $f_{p^n}: G \to G$ (which is in our case
the zero map as we already know) is *unramified*. Therefore
we have to analyse the induced map 
on differentials $f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G} \to \Omega_{G}$.
What we know that as you said the induced map
$f_{p^N}^*: T_e G \to T_e G$ on the tangent space *at the stalk 
on the neutral element* $e \in G$ is liteally given by multiplication 
with $p^n$.

Comment: And this is an isomorphism (since $p^n \in k^*$) and 
therefore the dual map on differentials *at stalk of $e$*
$f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G,e} \to \Omega_{G,e}$ is isomorphism as well,
especially $f_{p^N}$ is unramified at $e$.
The crucial point that confused me before was why in order to check
that $f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G} \to \Omega_{G}$ is unramified it was
*sufficient* to check it on $e$-stalk $\Omega_{G,e}$.

Comment: As Remy pointed out with reference to Bhatt's notes it's indeed
a fact that that a map on differentials of group schemes are
*completly determined* on how the map act on the stalk 
$\Omega_{G,e}$. For sake of completness: was this exactly
the argument you implicitly used in your proof in the comment
to show that $f_{p^N}$ is unramified?

Comment: Yup, this is indeed what I had mind