# Any finite flat commutative group scheme of $p$-power order is etale if $p$ is invertible on the base

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology, group-schemes, p-divisible-group-schemes

This question is immediately related to [Discriminant ideal in a member of Barsotti-Tate Group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359983/discriminant-ideal-in-a-member-of-barsotti-tate-group)
dealing with Barsotti–Tate groups and here I
would like to clarify [a proof presented by
Anonymous in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359983/discriminant-ideal-in-a-member-of-barsotti-tate-group#comment906624_359983) from linked thread which I do not completely understand. Although meanwhile I found another proofs of the claim below I have a big interest on understanding *this proof below*.

Assume $G$ is a finite flat commutative group scheme
over a field $k$ of
order $p^N$. Assume $p$ prime and $p \in k \setminus \{0\}$,
equivalently invertible on the base.

**Claim:** Any finite flat commutative group scheme of $p$-power order
is etale if $p$
is invertible on the base.

Anonymous' proof works as follows:
Firstly we reduce to case over a field (because a
finitely presented flat map is etale if it is
fibrewise etale). Since we assumed $G$ commutative
the multiplication by $p^N$ map $f_{p^N}: G \to G$
is well defined and by Deligne's theorem
$p^N$ kills $G$ since it's the order of $G$.
That means that $f_{p^N}$ is the zero map: equivalently
it factorizes over $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$.

What now comes I do not understand:

It is claimed that $f_{p^N}$ is unramified
"as the map on the tangent spaces is given
by $p^N$, which is invertible".

**Question I:** why is the induced by $f_{p^N}$
maps on tangent spaces given
by $p^N$?

**Question II:** assume we understand Question I.
Why does this imply $G$ is unramified?

when we can answer these two question we are done because unramified finite type schemes over a field are etale.

Comment: You don't need Deligne's theorem to prove this. For the standard proof, see, for example, 11.31 of Milne, Algebraic Groups, CUP, 2017.

Comment: Nor do you need to assume it's commutative. Another reference is Waterhouse *Introduction to affine group schemes*, §11.4, §14.4.

Comment: But if you insist on this argument, I follows since the derivative of $\mu \colon G \times G \to G$ is addition $T_e G \times T_e G \to T_e G$ (use $\mu \circ (\operatorname{id} \times e) = \operatorname{id} = \mu \circ (e \times \operatorname{id})$ where $e \colon \operatorname{Spec} k \to G$ is the unit). II is a near immediate consequence of the definitions (see e.g. Tags [00UT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00UT) and [00RS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RS)).

Comment: I finished the title (which ended mid-sentence), and added a link to the comment I think that you meant.  If I got the wrong comment, please fix it or let me know.

Comment: @LSpice: you linked the correct comment

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: This is the important point: the map between tangent spaces $T_e G$ over $e$ induced by $f_{p^N}= \mu^{p^N}$ is as you correctly remarked the multiplication by $p^N$. Since $p^n$ is inverible in $k$ this map $T_e G \to T_e G$ is an isomorphism and dualizing the (1) in
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00UT implies only that $f_{p^N}$ is unramified at the stalk $\Omega_e$; that is at the unit point $e$ (!) . But Anonymous clamed that this should imply that $f_{p^N}$ is unramified; that means is unramified at every point of $G$.

Comment: Ok, you're right, but differentials on a group scheme are determined by what happens at the identity. See for example Prop 3.3 of [Bhatt's notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/abelian_varieties.pdf) on abelian varieties. To be precise, $\Omega_{G/S} = \pi^*e^*\Omega_{G/S}$ for $\pi \colon G \to S$ a group scheme with unit $e \colon S \to G$. Similarly for a morphism of group schemes $\phi \colon G \to H$, the map $\phi^*\Omega_{H/S} \to \Omega_{G/S}$ is determined by $e^*\Omega_{H/S} \to e^*\Omega_{G/S}$ under pullback to $G$. This is standard and used all the time.

Comment: I understand. And how now we deduce from this observation that $G$ is unramified. As you said $f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G,e} \to \Omega_{G,e}$ determine $f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G} \to \Omega_{G}$. The first one was an isomorphism ($p^N$ invertible) therefore $f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G} \to \Omega_{G}$ as well. Why this imply $G$ unramified?

Comment: I think you can apply it to the morphism of group schemes $G \to 1$, which is both the map $f_{p^N}$ (when viewing $1 \subseteq G$ as a closed subscheme) and the structure morphisms $G \to \operatorname{Spec} k$.

Comment: Yes, I think I got it: $f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G,e} \to \Omega_{G,e}$ is simultaneously in isomorphism ($P^N$ invertible) and zero map (because induced by zero map $f_{p^N}$). With the argument you remarked from Bhatt's notes then same must be true for $f_{p^N}^*\Omega_{G} \to \Omega_{G}$ as well. Consequently $\Omega_{G}=0$. Fini. Thank you a lot!